# Trouble exporting invoices from Access to QuickBooks with form

Tags: ms-access, quickbooks, qodbc

I am currently filling out all of my invoice information in Access, does anyone have experience with exporting this info right into QuickBooks invoices?

Here is an image what I currently have:[image: Image of Invoice Form]

All I need now is to transfer this information to QuickBooks.

Comment: Have you done any research? What have you tried? AFAIK, Access cannot directly export to QuickBooks, although, apparently QuickBooks can import Excel/CSV files.

Answer (score 0):

I currently have an invoice system in Access and I push out invoices directly from Access to QuickBooks with one mouse click.

You likely best just export the invoice in some format that QB can import. However, if you want a “click” of a button solution, and one that instant sends the invoice to QB, then you need to grab a copy of the QuickBooks SDK.

I used the SDK to build an interface to QB using .net and Visual Studio. The reason for this approach was the SDK from QB has all kinds of sample code etc. on how to do this from .net.

However, you can skip the .net part. The QB sdk has a “com” interface, and that can be used from VBA.

Some outline and example code using VBA can be found here:

https://pulseinfomatics.com/microsoft-access-quickbooks-sdk-part-1/

I also used .net, since then the VBA code in Access becomes rather simple. And I can “swap” out the .net object and replace it with a sage 50, and sage 300 modules I have. The result is I don’t have to change my Access code to support 3 very different accounting systems from my Access application.

So using the SDK will allow you to push the invoice right into QB, and not have to mess with some import/export process which requires "user" interaction.